# How should redux-less (React) component should expose data upon trigger from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

There is a component where **I can't use redux/store**.
The components are functional (not class).
In some point, the parent component should get data from this component.
Scenario: user clicked on button, in the parent, and then I need to get data from the child component.
My current solution is to pass 2 parameters to the child component.
One to trigger the getData (boolean) 
Another call back function to be executed when triggered by the first param.
Is there more elegant way?
Thanks.

Comment: The most elegant way is to store the data as state in the parent (not the child), and pass it as props to the child. That way the parent “owns” the data, and already has access to it. If needed, you can pass a function to the child to allow the child to update the data.

Comment: wintvelt is totally right, this process is called "lifting the state up" https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html